# Creating a new instance of NSManagedObject class

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to create a new object of class Student but there is an error when I call the function `createnewStudent` saying

> Cannot invoke 'CreateStudent' with an argument list of type '(NSManagedObjectContext, combination: String, stream: String, name: String, DOB: NSDate, gender: UISegmentedControl!, DOA: NSDate, fathername: UITextField, mothername: UITextField, familyincome: Int, emailid: String, phonenumber: Int)’

How do I proceed?

This is my ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class PortalViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var coursePicker: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var combination: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var streamPrint: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var genderSelected: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var DOB: UIDatePicker!

@IBOutlet weak var studentName: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var fatherName: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var fathersIncome: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var mothersName: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var mothersIncome: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumber: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var emailID: UITextField!

var newStudent = Student()

let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate     as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
let stream = ["Science","Arts","Commerce"]
let combinationScience = ["PCM", "PMCs", "CBZ"]
let combinationArts = ["HEP","English","Kannada"]
let combinationCommerce = ["BBM", "Economics","xyz"]
var selectedRow = 0
func pickerView(pickerView : UIPickerView , didSelectRow row : Int ,     inComponent component : Int){
    switch component {
    case 0 :
        selectedRow = row
        streamPrint.text = stream[row]

        coursePicker.reloadAllComponents()


    case 1 :

        switch selectedRow {
        case 0: combination.text = combinationScience[row]
        case 1: combination.text = combinationArts[row]
        case 2: combination.text = combinationCommerce[row]
        default : combination.text = "combination"
        }

    default : selectedRow = 0
    }
}


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    switch component {
    case 0 : return stream[row]
    case 1 :
        switch selectedRow {
        case 0: return combinationScience[row]
        case 1: return combinationArts[row]
        case 2: return combinationCommerce[row]
        default: return nil
        }
    default: return nil
    }
}

@IBAction func proceed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var fi1 = fathersIncome.text.toInt()
    var fi2 = mothersIncome.text.toInt()
    var fi = fi1! + fi2!
    var newStudent = Student.CreateStudent(managedObjectContext!, combination: combination.text!, stream: streamPrint.text!, name: studentName.text!, DOB: DOB.date, gender: genderSelected, DOA: DOB.date, fathername: fatherName!, mothername: mothersName!, familyincome: fi, emailid: emailID.text!, phonenumber: phoneNumber.text.toInt()!)
}









override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
// Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

And this is my NSManagedObject file
    import Foundation
    import CoreData

```
class Student: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var combination: String
    @NSManaged var currentSemester: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var dateOfAdmition: NSDate
    @NSManaged var dateOfBirth: NSDate
    @NSManaged var emailID: String
    @NSManaged var familyIncome: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var fatherName: String
    @NSManaged var gender: String
    @NSManaged var motherName: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var phoneNumber: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var registerNumber: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var stream: String

    class func CreateStudent(moc : NSManagedObjectContext, combination : String, stream : String, name : String , DOB : NSDate, gender : String, DOA : NSDate,fathername :String, mothername: String, familyincome : Int , emailid : String, phonenumber : Int)-> Student{
        let newStudent = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Student", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Student
        newStudent.combination = combination
        newStudent.stream = stream
        newStudent.name = name
        newStudent.dateOfBirth = DOB
        newStudent.dateOfAdmition = DOA
        newStudent.fatherName = fathername
        newStudent.motherName = mothername
        newStudent.familyIncome = familyincome
        newStudent.emailID  = emailid
        newStudent.phoneNumber = phonenumber
        return newStudent
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a `UISegmentedControl` instance for the gender argument when you should be passing a `String` value.

Also check `fatherName` and `motherName` as you're passing in `UITextField` instances.